# how to view Apple TV purchases in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, appletv

I bought a TV series through Apple TV.  Watched the first episode, works fine.

Now I'd like to watch episode 2 on my MacBook.  I opened iTunes (11.0.2), logged in with my iTunes account, and can't find the TV series anywhere.

How do I watch a TV series I bought through Apple TV on my MacBook in iTunes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I must say I found this all very confusing.

Apple devices normally work so seamlessly together.  Why hide this functionality by a checkbox deep inside a preference pane?

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is that Apple might figure that if you buy a TV series on the Apple TV, that's the main device you're going to use to watch it. You can access any of your purchased content from the Purchased list in the iTunes Store, and download it from there, if you don't want "cloud" content displayed in iTunes, or if you don't want automatic downloads (you may not want everything downloaded automatically).